# Cardinality validation in SWRL

Tags: owl, cardinality, swrl

I have an object property with the same range and domain, and I want to check if a certain instance does not have an axiom either in the range or in the domain of this property.

I.E.,
`NOT EXISTS(isBaseFor(?p1, ?p2)) -> Error(?p1)` or
`NOT EXISTS(isBaseFor(?p2, ?p1)) -> Error(?p1)`

Already tried to do something such as `(isBaseFor= 0)(?p)` but with no success. I'm using SWRL tab in Protégé.

Comment: that won't work with standard inference given that in OWL and SWRL the *"Open World Assumption"* holds - and closing the world is cumbersome up to impossible

Comment: the better mechanism for this would be SHACL (or SHeX)